# Extracting a key from JSON file using jq

Tags: bash, jq

I have a JSON formatted file which has an Event field

```
for file in /home/ec2-user/Workspace/events_parts/*
do
        cat $file | jq '.Event'

done
```

I get the list of "Event" values extracted from JSON file.I want to assign this value to a bash variable so that I can use it for comparision later. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use `myVar=$(some bash commands)` to store the stdout into a variable and you call it like `echo "$myVar"`; putting `""` around `$myVar` to pretend the shell preprocess your string (trimming, new line, "")

or even you can put it into an array like this: `myArray=( $(some bash commands) )`